# how to authenticate route that do not match regexp - EXPRESS

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate route that is not `/api/login` or `/api/signup`

so i tried using

`app.use('/^\/api\/(?!signup|login).*$/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }));`

but when i run the app i get this error

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/^\/api\/(?:?!signup|login)\.(.*)$\/?(?=\/|$)/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: Your regex is actually invalid. This part `(?:?!signup|login)` is not ok, as the second `?` cannot quantify the `:` of the non-capturing group. You can test it on https://regex101.com/, which helps you analyze your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Express is using the `path-to-regexp` module: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

If you want to use a regex to match the routes you can just use a javascript regex object, instead of the string:

```
app.use(/^\/api\/(?!signup|login).*$/, passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }));
```

So the `path-to-regexp` module is not used to convert your string into a regex.
As Documented here:https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that express uses path-to-regexp, so it was trying to convert

`/^\/api\/(?!signup|login).*$/` 
to a regexp and I was trying to use **pure regex** for an Express.js route rule.

I had to use a JS regular expression object and wrap the regular expression in **slashes** (/) instead of **quotes** (')